# Return value in a specific column based on array formula result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using an array formula to find the largest value within a given month. Photo below ('Range of values') shows the values for each month, and I am selecting September as the criteria ("K5" in the formula below). Cell K5 will change based on the specific month I am looking for:

[image: Range of values]

Formula:
{=MAX(IF(E8:P8=K5,E12:P21,""))}

Result:
63,490

Requirement:
I need to have a cell with the result, and a cell next to it with the corresponding 'Location', which in this case would be **6**.

What would be the best formula to use in the case where you are not confined to a single column for the value lookup?

Typical Vlookup and Index/Match as I understand are limited as they require a single column to look up a value. The array is outside of that scope, but I feel I may be overthinking it, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have Excel 365 current channel you can use this formula to return both values:

```
=LET(data,A1:D5,
selectMonth,B7,
dataMonth,CHOOSECOLS(data,1,MATCH(selectMonth,CHOOSEROWS(data,1),0)),
TAKE(SORT(dataMonth,2,-1),2))
```

The basic idea is to first reduce the data range to the first column and the month that should be evaluated.

Then sort that "range" descending by the months values (= column 2 of new range) and take the first 2 rows (including header) - as this is the max value.

[image]